# QTableWidget display certain decimals like excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

My question is about the way the `QTableWidget` displays the cell values.

I'd like for the cell to show only three decimals when it's not being edited and show the full value when you double click for editing.

---

I am doing calculations in background and then setting the cell value afterwards.

```
V_D = 3/0.7
self.TableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(V_D)))
```

Similar to the way excel formats the cell to show certain number of digits.

Full Value:

[image]

Display Value:

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to use a delegate and override the paint method that is responsible for showing what looks in normal state, I have built the following class based on the above.

```
class FloatDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, decimals, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.nDecimals = decimals

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
        try:
            number = float(value)
            painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignLeft, "{:.{}f}".format(number, self.nDecimals))
        except :
            QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
```

In your case you should use it as follows:

```
self.TableWidget.setItemDelegate(FloatDelegate(3))
```

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QTableWidget()
    w.setColumnCount(8)
    w.setRowCount(8)
    for i in range(w.rowCount()):
        for j in range(w.columnCount()):
            number = (i+1)/(j+1)
            w.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(number)))
    w.setItemDelegate(FloatDelegate(3, w))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

*Plus:*

By Row o Column:

```
#only column 2
setItemDelegateForColumn(2, FloatDelegate(3))
#only row 2
setItemDelegateForRow(2, FloatDelegate(3))
```

If you want to apply only to cell 2,3

```
def paint(self, painter, option, index):
   if index.row() == 2 and index.column() == 3:
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
        try:
            number = float(value)
            painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignLeft, "{:.{}f}".format(number, self.nDecimals))
        except :
            QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
    else:
        QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
```

**Update:**

- QStyledItemDelegate:

  ```py
  from math import log10

  class FloatDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
      def __init__(self, decimals, parent=None):
          super(FloatDelegate, self).__init__(parent=parent)
          self.nDecimals = decimals

      def displayText(self, value, locale):
          try:
              number = float(value)
          except ValueError:
              return super(FloatDelegate, self).displayText(value, locale)
          else:
              precision = log10(number) + 1 + self.nDecimals
              return locale.toString(number, f='f', prec=precision)
  ```

Comment: Cool makes sense. What if a cell is blank? It crashes the program. Also, can you .setItemDelegate on certain cells and not just the entire table?

Comment: It still crashes, when I tested the code you gave, it's fine until I delete what is in the cell and then it crashes

Comment: The new code you posted worked, not sure if you saw the part of my comment if you can .setItemDelegate certain cells

Comment: Any cells, for example sake, lets say row 2 only

Comment: Any idea why my .setTextAlignment on table cells work for some but not others? It started giving me an error after I updated the paint code, but when I deleted the code you provided, it still doesn't work for all cells. Have you had this problem?

Comment: Share an mvce, and please run it and verify that functions before sharing it, it is tedious to have to correct import errors.

Comment: I figured it out, I created a new QTableWidgetItem

Comment: Thanks for the update eyllanesc, should there be return here just before ```super(FloatDelegate, self).displayText(value, locale)``` in the except ValueError: ?